# Get current Post info inside Widget method

Tags: wordpress, widget

How to get current post's information, e.g. get_category(), get_post_title(), etc., from inside `widget` method (code below), assuming the widget is placed inside the post loop?

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // outputs the content of the widget
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the post id with:

`$post_id = $GLOBALS['post']->ID;`

With the $post_id you can get any informations you need.

Comment: Hi Phillip. It worked! Is it a good practice to code like that on WordPress? Is there another way to get these information inside a class method on functions.php?